# How can I show ads and it gives me this error

Tags: android, admob, runtime-error, ads, timeoutexception

My Admob ads not showing, I got this error

```
E/Ads: Error waiting for future.
    java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:177)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.g.a(:com.google.android.gms@16089017@16.0.89 (040306-239467275):12)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.cache.l.a(:com.google.android.gms@16089017@16.0.89 (040306-239467275):5)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.signals.gmscore.q.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
    />
```

//java code
MobileAds.initialize(HomeActivity.this,  getString(R.string.app_ad_unit_id));

```
    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: Please post your minimal working code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means request of ads is time out because of **less ads**.If you want to show your ads make many time request to load ads(**put your request code into for loop and make loop in 1000 times**)in this case ads may be load.I also make this type code and ads can Load.

But make sure you first **add test id** in your code because of in test case only ads is give to testing ads if you are **show original ads** to make your project **live in play store**.So,make sure to add test id in your code.

If crash your app it means some mistake in your code So,if crash your app please put your code.

I hope this can help You!

Thank You.

Comment: Hello Sir, Thank you for your reply. I have put test ads and work well but the real is not  show and i will try do for loop and told you result

Comment: It does not work as ads are not showing and gives the same error

Comment: @الهرمالرابع don't try production ads while development. Your account will be blocked otherwise

Comment: @الهرمالرابع don't worry your ads is showing when you live your app.